# mysql - select result of two conditionals for the same table in one query

Tags: mysql, select

I am struggling to get correct results with this.  I want to test if both, or either, exist.  In `results` table, 'michael' exists while 'mike' does not.

```
$stmt = $dbnet->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT cats AS cats1 FROM results WHERE name = :original) AS a,
        (SELECT cats AS cats2 FROM results WHERE name = :parsed) AS b
");

$binding = array(
    'original' => 'michael',
    'parsed' => 'mike'
);
$stmt->execute($binding);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//if there was a result then output
if($results)
{
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($results,1).'</pre>';
}
```

I get no results with this even though 'michael' is in the database.

If I test for `'original' => 'michael', 'parsed' => 'michael'` I get results...both the same of course since I tested the same value for each :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cats1] => 6,11
            [cats2] => 6,11
        )

)
```

What I expect is one of the following :

- no results meaning neither michael or mike exist
- result for cats1 and empty for cats2 (michael exists mike does not)
- empty for cats1 and result for cats2 (mike exists michael does not)

No, I cannot use `WHERE name = 'michael' OR name = 'mike'` because what I do after changes depending if both have results or just one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as epxected... both always needs a result even if that is empty to return correctly.

```
$stmt = $dbnet->prepare("
    SELECT
        IFNULL( (SELECT cats AS cats1 FROM results WHERE name = :original), '') AS a,
        IFNULL( (SELECT cats AS cats2 FROM results WHERE name = :parsed), '') AS b
");
```